# How to return array of tuples in a tableview?

Tags: swift, uikit

I want to create and return an array of tuples in a tableView function but I am not sure how. I believe one method is to do so by decomposing the tuple but I'm not sure how to execute in this case. I know the last tableView is incorrect as it doesn't return (String, String) that is just my attempt.

```
class RideHistoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


let rideHistory: [(String,String)] = [("Driver: Joe, 12/29/2021", "$26.50"),
                   ("Driver: Sandra, 01/03/2022", "$13.10"),
                   ("Driver: Hank, 01/11/2022", "$16.20"),
                   ("Driver: Michelle, 01/19/2022", "$8.50")]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier:"TableViewCell")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Code Here
    return self.rideHistory.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Code Here
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.rideHistory[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Use like `self.rideHistory[indexPath.row].0` or `self.rideHistory[indexPath.row].1`

Comment: When you say “return” do you mean “assign value to” instead? Like setting a value in the returned cell, `cell.textLabel?.text = …some value`?

Comment: No the correct wording would have been access, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can access that tuple value by there index(0,1,2,3).**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Code Here
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.rideHistory[indexPath.row].0
    print(self.rideHistory[indexPath.row].0) // Driver: Joe, 12/29/2021
    print(self.rideHistory[indexPath.row].1) // $26.50
    
    return cell
}
```